# How to arrange time series data into ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, time-series

I have a dataframe with timeseries data

| Timestamp | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 10-26-22 10.00 AM | 1 |
| 10-26-22 09.04 AM | 5 |
| 10.26-22 10.06 AM | 6 |
| -------- | -------- |
| 10-27-22 3.32 AM | 9 |
| 10-27-22 3.36 PM | 5 |
| 10-27-22 3.31 PM | 8 |
| -------- | -------- |
| 10-27-22 3.37 AM | 8.23 |
| 10-28-22 4.20 AM | 7.2 |

I tried to sort the timestamp column into ascending order by :

df.sort_values("Timestamp", ascending = True, inplace= True)

but this code is not working. I want to get the data like this:

| Timestamp | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 10-26-22 09.04 AM | 1 |
| 10-26-22 10.00 AM | 5 |
| 10-26-22 10.06 AM | 6 |
| -------- | -------- |
| 10-27-22 3.31 AM | 9 |
| 10-27-22 3.32 PM | 5 |
| 10-27-22 3.36 PM | 8 |
| ------ | -------- |
| 10-27-22 3.37 AM | 8.23 |
| 10-28-22 4.20 AM | 7.2 |

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to drill down to the timestamp then convert the format before using the sort_values function on the dataframe..

You should look through the documentation. This is scarcely implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` parameter of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to convert the string to datetime internally with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and the `%m-%d-%y %H.%M %p` format:

```
df.sort_values(by='Timestamp', key=lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s, format='%m-%d-%y %H.%M %p'))
```

Output:

```
           Timestamp  Values
1  10-26-22 09.04 AM    5.00
0  10-26-22 10.00 AM    1.00
2  10-26-22 10.06 AM    6.00
5   10-27-22 3.31 PM    8.00
3   10-27-22 3.32 AM    9.00
4   10-27-22 3.36 PM    5.00
6   10-27-22 3.37 AM    8.23
7   10-28-22 4.20 AM    7.20
```

Alternatively, assign a dummy column:

```
(df.assign(key=pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%m-%d-%y %H.%M %p'))
   .sort_values(by='key')
)
```